# R POSIXct of non existing time stamp due to CET/CEST shift

Tags: r, timestamp, dst, posixct

I am having a sql query from a database which unfortunately does not handle time time shifts CET <-> CEST very well. One day always has 24 hours no matter if it has 23 when changing CET to CEST or 25 when changing from CEST to CET.
If I want to change the type of a time stamp from character to POSIXct the time information gets lost.

```
tsCharacter <- c("2016-03-27 01:00:00", "2016-03-27 02:00:00", "2016-03-27 03:00:00")
as.POSIXct(tsCharacter)
"2016-03-27 CET" "2016-03-27 CET" "2016-03-27 CET"
```

Due to shift from CET to CEST "2016-03-27 02:00:00" should no exist and that is probably why I get the false transformation.

Anybody knows a smart way around this without cleaning the data by hand?

Regards!

Comment: how about 

as.POSIXct(strptime(tsCharacter, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

Comment: You can hack it by changing the timezone to eg "Africa/Algiers" which does not have daylight saving, so is effectively on CET all year round.

Comment: Thanks to sandipan, that works quite fine. The "Africa/Algiers" solution does not work for me, since I need CET/CEST in the end.